# Install arbitrary data files in fixed location with Automake?

Tags: autotools, automake

How can I tell Automake to install arbitrary data files in places I want?

I have some files I need to put in specific places, e.g. "`datafile1`", in my project, needs to be copied to "`/usr/MyProduct/flash_memory`".

- "`/usr/MyProduct/flash_memory`" is an absolute path that I can't change.
- "`datafile1`" is a binary data file that is not "built" by `make`, but just needs to be copied by `make install`.
- I can't bear on `make dist`. It needs to be copied by `make install` (its a long explanation, so, please just take this into account).
- I rather not use `install-hook`, but prefer to have a more elegant approach (if possible).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do not use full paths in your Makefile.am.  Ever.  You can tell automake to put the `datafile1` in `$(datadir)` which will expand to `$(prefix)/share/MyProduct`, or you can define `flash_DIR` to expand to `$(prefix)/MyProduct/flash_memory` and put the files there, but the end user must be allowed to set `$(prefix)` either to `/usr` or to something else.  What you want to do in Makefile.am is:

```
flashdir = $(prefix)/$(PACKAGE)/flash_memory
flash_DATA = datafile1
```

(It would probably be more appropriate to use `$(prefix)/@PACKAGE@/flash_memory`, since PACKAGE probably should not be modifiable at make time, but I don't think this is terribly important.)

Then, when you are a user, run `make install` with prefix set to `/usr`.  If you try to use an absolute path in the Makefile.am, it will disallow staged installations (ie setting DESTDIR), will restrict user flexibility, and is the *wrong* thing to do.  The main point is that the package maintainer does not get to choose the final location; that is a decision for the user.

Comment: As I sayd before, "`/usr/MyProduct/flash_memory`" is an absolute path that I can't change. Its not my choice. Ignoring that, I tried "`confdir=... conf_DATA=datafile1`" but it didn't work. Any hint? Thanks

Comment: @fljx When you say "I cannot change", do you mean "I" as the user installing the package, or do you mean "I" when you are the package maintainer.  If the former, my answer works.  If you mean the latter, then stop using automake;  you are abusing the tool.

Comment: I mean "I, the worker that obeys my boss". Anyway, I changed `confdir` to "`confdir  = $(prefix)/usr/awmg/flash/`" and it works. The absolute path does not. I just want to understand why, now... Thanks again!

Comment: you should always respect $(prefix) and $(DESTDIR). it makes packaging so much easier (e.g. someone wants to create debian/ubuntu packages one day...) and the default will (basically) satisfy your boss. just create a wrapper scripts that runs configure with "--prefix=/usr" and tell them that this is the way to configure your program rather than calling configure directly

Comment: @umlaeute - Thank you for pointing that out, but DESTDIR should not be prepended to flashdir since automake prepends DESTDIR in the `install-flashDATA` rule.  Is there something in my solution that requires a DESTDIR to be prepended?

Comment: no that's fine; my point was mainly that one shouldn't be too clever when trying to force installation targets (and respecting  DESTDIR is somehow contradictory with "absolute paths"). even though somebody might urge you to do something in a certain way, you can still do it in a standard-confirmant way that allows the specific case (and make a wrapper that makes the specific case the default)

Comment: `$(datadir)` expands to `$(prefix)/share`, while `$(pkgdatadir)` expands to `$(prefix)/share/$(PACKAGE)`. If you need stuff in a subdirectory with the name of your package, then you should use `pkgdata_DATA = myfile`

Comment: *"It would probably be more appropriate to use `$(prefix)/@PACKAGE@/flash_memory`..."* - I believe Automake uses `@PACKAGE_TARNAME@`. Or it does so for `docdir = ${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}`.