# Configure automake to install extra programs

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, automake

My project is a library and automake is configured to build it and test it. There is also additional target which builds demo application for my library. It's defined in `Makefile.am` as `EXTRA_PROGRAMS`. I'd like to be able to install with `make install` or similar. Is there a way to do it but still keep optionality of this target (i.e. simply defining this target in `bin_PROGRAMS` will make this target required)?

Comment: Possible duplicate [automake: install arbitrary data files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721826/automake-install-arbitrary-data-files)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this sort of thing is to have `configure` substitute the value into `bin_PROGRAMS` conditionally.  In your `Makefile.am` this would look like:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main-program $(test_program)
EXTRA_PROGRAMS = test-program
```

Then in configure.in you'd do something like:

```
if mumble; then
  test_program=test-program
fi
AC_SUBST(test_program)
```