# Preserve data file prefix when using dist_pkgdata_DATA?

Tags: autotools, automake, datadirectory

Our test data is organized with two folders. We have `TestData/` and `TestVectors/`, depending on the form of the data:

```
- TestData
  |
  + a.dat
  + b.dat
  + ...

- TestVector
  |
  + x.vec
  + y.vec
  + ...
```

[Our `Makefile.am`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools) has:

```
dist_pkgdata_DATA = \
   $(testdata_FILES) \
   $(testvector_FILES)

testdata_FILES = \
   TestData/a.dat TestData/b.dat \
   ...

testvector_FILES = \
   TestVectors/x.vec TestVectors/y.vec \
   ...
```

Automake installs them in `@datadir@/@PACKAGE@/`, but we lose the `TestData` and `TestVectors` prefix upon installation. That is, once installed, all the files are lumped together:

```
- @datadir@/@PACKAGE@/
  |
  + a.dat
  + b.dat
  + ...
  + x.vec
  + y.vec
  + ...
```

There's a very similar question at [Install arbitrary data files in arbitrary locations with Automake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10721826/608639), but I am not quite following what needs to be done to ensure `make install` works as expected.

My question is, how do we preserve the prefix of `TestData` or `TestVectors` during install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `nobase` prefix was invented for.  The name stands for "don't call basename" and would be used like:

```
nobase_dist_pkgdata_DATA = \
    $(testdata_FILES) \
    $(testvector_FILES)
```

This should result in the listed files keeping their directory names in the install tree.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how do we preserve the prefix of TestData or TestVectors during install?

Ordinarily, Automake computes the basename of each target and uses that at install time to record the file directly in the designated directory.  If the target names contain directory prefixes that you want to propagate into the installed image then you can tell Automake about it by using the `nobase_` prefix on the relevant target variable.  This can be combined with other prefixes such as `dist_`.  For example,

```
nobase_dist_pkgdata_DATA = \
   $(testdata_FILES) \
   $(testvector_FILES)
```

Prefixes in general are described in [section 3.3 of the Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Uniform.html#Uniform), and `nobase_` in particular is detailed in [section 12.1 of the Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Basics-of-Installation.html#Basics-of-Installation).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I used [3.3 The Uniform Naming Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Uniform.html) and followed it to [8.4 Program and Library Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html#Program-and-Library-Variables). Unfortunately some things like `nobase_` are not documented in 8.4 even though 3.3 tells us to go there. Ugh...

Comment: Thanks again @John. That fixed it for me.